# How to resolve the error message when adding SQS redrive policy for deadletter queue created using for_each

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want terraform to associate my SQS Management Event with my DLQ management event and i want the same thing done with SQS Data Event and DLQ Data Event.I am getting error messages when i run apply on my code below.please I need some help.

```
.tfvars

sqs_queue_names = ["CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event", "CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event"]

dead_queue_names = ["CloudTrail_DLQ_Management_Event", "CloudTrail_DLQ_Data_Event"]
```

```
variable.tf 

variable "sqs_queue_names"{
  description = "The name of different SQS to be created"
  type        = set(string)
}

variable "dead_queue_names"{
  description = "The name of different Dead Queues to be created"
  type        = set(string)
}
```

```
main.tf

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS"{

    for_each                   = var.sqs_queue_names
    name                       = each.value
    redrive_policy = jsonencode({
        deadLetterTargetArn    = values(aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ)[*].arn
        maxReceiveCount        = var.max_receive_count
    })

    tags = var.default_tags
    
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ"{

    for_each                   = var.dead_queue_names
    name                       = each.value
   
    tags = var.default_tags
}
```

```
ERROR MESSAGES:
Error: error creating SQS Queue (CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event): InvalidParameterValue: Value {"deadLetterTargetArn":["arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:CloudTrail_DLQ_Data_Event","arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:CloudTrail_DLQ_Management_Event"],"maxReceiveCount":10} for parameter RedrivePolicy is invalid. Reason: Invalid value for deadLetterTargetArn.
│       status code: 400, request id: 9663b896-d86f-569e-92e2-e17152c2db26
│ 
│   with aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS["CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event"],
│   on main.tf line 5, in resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS":
│    5: resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS"{
│ 
╵
╷
│ Error: error creating SQS Queue (CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event): InvalidParameterValue: Value {"deadLetterTargetArn":["arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:CloudTrail_DLQ_Data_Event","arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:123456789012:CloudTrail_DLQ_Management_Event"],"maxReceiveCount":10} for parameter RedrivePolicy is invalid. Reason: Invalid value for deadLetterTargetArn.
│       status code: 400, request id: 88b8e4c5-1d50-5559-92f8-bd2297fd231f
│ 
│   with aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS["CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event"],
│   on main.tf line 5, in resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS":
│    5: resource "aws_sqs_queue" "CloudTrail_SQS"{
```

Comment: This seems as same question as your previous one. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are not associating the dead letter queue with the corresponding SQS queue. `values(aws_sqs_queue.CloudTrail_SQS_DLQ)[*].arn` - this essentially passes every dead letter queue ARN for each SQS queue, it does not passes to correct ARN only.

In order to overcome this, I suggest creating a module where we can tie together the SQS queue and its DLQ. We can name for now `my_sqs`:

`my_sqs/variables.tf`:

```
variable "sqs_queue_name"{
  description = "The name of different SQS to be created"
  type        = string
}

variable "dead_queue_name"{
  description = "The name of different Dead Queues to be created"
  type        = string
}

variable "max_receive_count" {
    type = number
}
```

`my_sqs/main.tf`:

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "sqs" {
  name  = var.sqs_queue_name

  redrive_policy = jsonencode({
    deadLetterTargetArn = aws_sqs_queue.dlq.arn
    maxReceiveCount     = var.max_receive_count
  })
}

resource "aws_sqs_queue" "dlq" {
  name  = var.dead_queue_name
}
```

Now we can use this module like this:

`variables.tf`:

```
# Please not, we are tying the SQS and the DQL together here as well.
variable "queue_names" {
  default = [
    {
      sqs_name = "CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event"
      dlq_name = "CloudTrail_DLQ_Management_Event"
    },
    {
      sqs_name = "CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event"
      dlq_name = "CloudTrail_DLQ_Data_Event"
    }
  ]
}
```

From the `main.tf` we call the module we created above:

`main.tf`:

```
module "my_sqs" {
  source = "./my_sqs"
  for_each = {
    for sqs, dlq in var.queue_names : sqs => dlq
  }
  sqs_queue_name    = each.value.sqs_name
  dead_queue_name   = each.value.dlq_name
  max_receive_count = 4
}
```

Please note, this example may work with the latest Terraform versions. It may not work with an older version which does not support having a `for_each` on a `module`.

Comment: thank for your fantastic answer..it worked when  I do it the way you said but I want to use Terragrunt to call the module that create the resources

Comment: This is my Terragrunt.hcl  inputs = {
  cloudtrail_event_log_bucket_name = "aws-cloudtrailbucket-sqs-logs"
  sqs_queue_names                  = ["CloudTrail_SQS_Management_Event", "CloudTrail_SQS_Data_Event"]
  dead_queue_names                 = ["CloudTrail_DLQ_Management_Event", "CloudTrail_DLQ_Data_Event"]

Comment: @ Ervin I have reposted the question with my Terragrunt.hcl configuration

Comment: Great, I'm not that familiar with Terragrunt, other people can help you with a new question.

Comment: i decided to go with your suggested answer.....thank you so much

Comment: i would like to ask you more question regarding the provider solution

Comment: i posted the question @Ervin